# Finding out the eccentricity of the curve of projection of circle on a plane

Tags: conic-sections, 3d

> Suppose $AB$ is a diameter of a circle and $P$ is a plane through $AB$ making angle $a$ with the plane of the circle.If diameter of the circle be $2A$,then the question is to find out the eccentricity of the curve of projection of the circle on $P$

I am aware of the fact that the projected area on a plane is the area of circle times $\cos$ of the angle between the circle and the plane.By this I could find out the projected area of the circle on the plane as $\pi A^2 \cos a $ Comparing this with the area of ellipse I assumed the semi minor axis as $A\cos a$ and semi major axis as $A$ which gives eccentricity as $\sin a$ but I am not sure if this approach is correct.Any ideas?Thanks.

Comment: Compute the ellipse axis. This gives you access to the eccentricity.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Taking hint of your comment I calculated the eccentricity to be $\sin a$ but I am not sure if the approach is correct.Please have a look at the edited question.

Comment: How do you get this result ? What is your formula for the eccentricity ?

Comment: I am not sure of the result and i just used the formula of eccentricity as $e^2=1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}$

Comment: That's perfect.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But I had to assume that semi minor axis is $A\cos a$ which makes me feel that this approach is incorrect

Comment: "makes me feel that this approach is incorrect": why ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I couldnot get how can the semi minor axis be found directly instead

Comment: Instead of what ???